# installshield sharepoint deployment

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, installshield

I am new to sharepoint and installshield. My responsiblity is to build and deploy the sharepoint solution as a package using istallsheild. Previously I was using solution package wsp and content database restoration. But now the client wants to deliver the total solution i.e. dlls, ascx files, xml files, servce files(.cs), feature files using installsjield from development server to another (test and/or client) server.

Can any body help me on this: how to do the sharepoint deployment using installshield?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are using SharePoint solutions to package dll's, ascx and xml files for deployment to a sharepoint server. These solutions are built using a tool like **[WSPBuilder](http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder)**.

If not: YOU SHOULD!

- If so: Why not use **[SharePoint Installer](http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller)**? It is an installer wrapper around a .wsp (SharePoint solution) file. It will check for the existence of a sharepoint installation, if the required services are started etc.
- For deployment to a test machine: Why would you need the .cs files? If you want to test (debug) code on a test machine, I suggest you use either continuous integration using a tool like [CruiseControl.NET](http://ccnet.thoughtworks.com/), or just install Visual Studio on the test machine (which I presume to be a dev test, not a client test machine) and get the latest version, do a build, then roll out the solution.
- And what do you mean with "client" server? is there some windows app that's communicating with sharepoint included in the installer? If so, I suggest separating the SharePoint solution from the actual windows app. They might share DLL's but are not supposed to be in the same installer.

Comment: The .cs files would be deployed when using JIT compilation in your web app. "Client" as in "the server owned by the client who is paying me to complete this project".

Comment: Currently I am using manifest and ddf file to create wsp and deploy on the test server. But now the requirement from the client has changed. They want to deploy on the test server/client's server machine with installshield. the client wants the deployment should be done with a single click and installshield should be used. Can any body help on how to do this?

Comment: The sharepoint installer works like installshield, it creates an exe setup also. Wouldn't even know how to do a solution deployment using InstallShield, SharePoint installer does everything for you (install wsp etc.) nad is made for just this situation. Furthermore, it's open source, your boss should like not having to pay for software :-D!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with InstallShield, but if it has the ability to invoke the command line or batch files, you could treat it exactlly like the SP Installer, having it act as a wrapper to the correct stsadm calls which deploy your solution in the farm. Regardless, you will want to deploy via the SharePoint deployment model (WSPs and stsadm) so that changes are propagated across the entire farm, and you aren't forced to run an installer on each individual server in the farm.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a tool (open source - saf.codeplex.com) to automate the Sharepoint components using MSBuild/Features/STSADM etc. Recently they have upgraded this to use WIX so that we can deploy any SharePoint components.

saf.codeplex.com

It has got an very good documentation and also we got a good support in fixing and implementing the SharePoint automated deployment in our premise.

Thanks
BalamuruganK